# data driven development framework with Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, frameworks, tdd, bdd

Does anybody know a good data driven development framework/library/gem for Ruby? I know a ton for Rails but I couldn't find anything for Ruby itself. I have a standalone Ruby app and I want to generate test data and write test cases for different data sets. I don't want to use fixtures. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist)? The readme mentions it can work without Rails.

Comment: I exactly want something like this. Are you sure about it saying it work without Rails? I couldn't see anything mentioned about that in the Readme.

Comment: @SaitIlhaner There's a section called "Blueprints on Plain Old Ruby Objects" - "Plain Old Ruby Objects" is a fancy term for non-active-model/non-Rails objects.